# Allow access to one directory with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following code which works perfectly, but I want to allow access to the /assets directory?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.* controller.php
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Could someone give me a little line of code or two to help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets
```